# .htaccess rewriting url from subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have entries in my .htaccess that goes like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ dubai/ [R]
RewriteRule ^dubai/$ page/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ pakistan/ [R]
RewriteRule ^pakistan/$ page/index.php [L]
```

basically I want to make a rule that can handle countries as part of the rewrite, the above code i have is redundant and can cause the file to grow unnecessarily.

Is there a way to automatically redirect the page to `page/index.php` if it serves for any countries? I tried putting this line to the last line above:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\/]*)/$ page/index.php
```

My problem is it no longer reads the succeeding rules for the other pages to serve. The below lines are samples of the rules just below the last one above:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\/]*)rent/$ page/index.php?methodcall=rent&for=Rent
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\/]*)landlords/$ page/index.php?methodcall=landlords
```

What happens is the get vars are no longer read by index.php file, if i remove the last rewriterule the key vars are read properly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\/?)$ page/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/rent(\/?)$ page/index.php?methodcall=rent&for=Rent [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/landlords(\/?)$ page/index.php?methodcall=landlords [NC,QSA,L]
```